# Add data-attribute and class to all images in WP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filter

I have created a custom field for images in Wordpress, which is created and saving correctly using the below code.

However, I need this field `vimeo-id` to be inserted into any `<img>` tag that is inserted into the WYSIWYG editor (as a `data` attribute), if a value is present for the field on that image. Also, if the value is present, I'd also like to add the class `.video-thumb` to the image.

**Current Output** is something like the following:

```
<img src="ImageURL.jpg" alt="Image Alt" width="1920" height="1080" class="size-full wp-image-0000">
```

**Desired Output** (if a vimeo-id is present):

```
<img src="ImageURL.jpg" alt="Image Alt" width="1920" height="1080" class="size-full wp-image-0000 video-thumb" data-vimeo-id="12345678">
```

Can anybody help be with this?

**Custom Field Function**

```
/* Add custom field to attachment */
function image_attachment_add_custom_fields($form_fields, $post) {
    $form_fields["vimeo-id"] = array(
        "label" => __("Vimeo ID"),
        "input" => "text",
        "value" => get_post_meta($post->ID, "vimeo-id", true),
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "image_attachment_add_custom_fields", null, 2);

/* Save custom field value */
function image_attachment_save_custom_fields($post, $attachment) {
    if(isset($attachment['vimeo-id'])) {
        update_post_meta($post['ID'], 'vimeo-id', $attachment['vimeo-id']);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post['ID'], 'vimeo-id');
    }
    return $post;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "image_attachment_save_custom_fields", null , 2);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'add_vimeo_data_to_image', 10, 2 );

function add_vimeo_data_to_image( $html, $attachment_id ) 
{
    if ($attachment_id)
    {
        //check if there is vimeo video id for the image
        $vimeo_id = get_post_meta($attachment_id, 'vimeo-id', true);

        //if there is a vimeo id set for the image, add class and data-attr
        if ($vimeo_id)
        {
            $document = new DOMDocument();
            $document->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

            $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');

            foreach ($imgs as $img)
            {
                //get the current class
                $current_image_class = $img->getAttribute('class');

                //add new class along with current class
                $img->setAttribute('class',$current_image_class . ' video-thumb');

                //add the data attribute
                $img->setAttribute('data-vimeo-id', $vimeo_id);
            }

            $html = $document->saveHTML();
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

This will get the attachment id and checks for the vimeo id in the database. If it finds vimeo id, then get the image using dom document and add the new **class (video-thumb)** and the **data attribute (data-vimeo-id)**. to the image.

But if your PHP version less than `PHP 5.4` and Libxml is less than `Libxml 2.6`, then `$document->loadHTML` does not have the second option parameter. In that you have to use:

```
# remove <!DOCTYPE
$document->removeChild($document->doctype);

# remove <html><body></body></html>
$document->replaceChild($document->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $document->firstChild);

$html = $document->saveHTML();
```

or

```
$html = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|head|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $html);
```

to get the HTML without Doctype, head and body.

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: Hi @sabari. Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately however, when placing this into my functions.php file, and then trying to place an image in the WP editor, nothing appears, it is almost as if it is freezing? I love the look of what your code is doing, but as I say it is not seeming to function in the backend (meaning I cannot test it). Any idea how to resolve? Thanks

Comment: I think the best option is to enable debug in wp-config.php, then open the network tab in chrome or firefox and check what is the response of your request when the Insert in to post button is clicked.

Comment: When debug is enabled, I see the following message at the top of the editor page: 
Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use__construct()
instead. in /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3457

When I click Add Media, the images do not load either, only in debug mode.

Comment: I am not sure about the issue. If only I can get the access I can check the issue. My WordPress version is 4.3 and it works fine for me. Where did you add this filter?

Comment: Did you check what the network tab is showing when you click on insert post or add media button?

Comment: @dungey_140 Did you check ?

Comment: Hey @sabari, apologies for the slow reply! The code is being added at the end of my functions.php file. And yes, the Add Media button was working before, and does still work if I remove this snippet. Wordpress Version 4.3.1
The add media button does still work, but once you have selected your image and insert into the post, no code is generated in the editor?

Comment: @dungey_140 You need to check your network tab and check what is happening there when you click insert in to post. I think there may be some error. Please check that.

Comment: Hi @sabari, I'm not all that familiar with the network tab in terms of deciphering what is being shown. Here is an image of the network tab just after clicking 'Insert to Post', when the image doesn't appear in the editor. If this is not of much use, I could provide you with a login to take a look? Shall we migrate this to chat?

http://i68.tinypic.com/169q9ti.png

Comment: @dungey_140 Yes we can chat

Comment: I've just added you to a chat room, not done it before so hopefully setup correctly?

Comment: I cannot thank @sabari enough for his efforts in helping me to resolve this issue. The above answer is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question but the most simplistic way that I can think of is.

First start by creating a custom function inside of your functions.php file.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_image_size( 'vimeo', 1920, 1080 );`
```

Then simply just paste this code `<?php the_post_thumbnail('vimeo', array( 'class'  => "vimeo-id")); ?>` and you should be set.

You can of course edit around with the functions part but the output pretty much remains the same.

Comment: Hey @open. Thanks for the response. I think I need something a little more complex than this, as I need to apply the new data and class to all images inside the_content. I can't add images individually in the template files.

Comment: @dungey_140 - Why not just strip the `<img>` tags completely from the image url then and then just pull the image url manually and echo out the custom taxonomy or what ever it is you're using into the data field? The sloppy way for sure but it would probably work.  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrieveing-featured-image-url

Comment: I need the_content to appear as setup by the client. No manual editing is possible of the template files.